# How to handle NullReferenceException when Linq to xml parsing attribute

Tags: linq, exception, linq-to-xml, nullreferenceexception

I have a simple xml.

```
        var FieldsInData = from fields in xdoc.Descendants("DataRecord")
                           select fields;
```

Now i have n different XElement items in FildsInData.

```
        foreach (var item in FieldsInData)
        {
            //working
            String id = item.Attribute("id").Value;
            //now i get a nullReferenceException because that XElement item has no Attribute called **fail**
            String notExistingAttribute = item.Attribute("fail").Value;
        }
```

With that fail attribute i get nullReferenceException, because it is not there. Sometimes it is, sometimes it is not. How do i handle that gracefully?

I tryed using value.SingleOrDefault(); but i get another exception because it is IEnumerable of Char.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to check for `null`:

```
String notExistingAttribute = "";

var attribute =  item.Attribute("fail");
if(attribute != null)
    notExistingAttribute = attribute.Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add another way to do this, you could also abuse Extension Methods for null checking:

```
public static class XmlExtensions 
{
    public static string ValueOrDefault(this XAttribute attribute) 
    {
        return attribute == null ? null : attribute.Value;
    }
}
```

And then use it like that:

```
string notExistingAttribute = item.Attribute("fail").ValueOrDefault();
```

Comment: Strictly, to follow the 'ValueOrDefault' pattern this should have a second parameter which allows you to specify the Default. Otherwise I'd call it 'ValueOrNull'. :-)